# Let $A$ and $B$ be two real symmetric matrices such that $A^{2018} = B^{2018}$. Show that $\cos A = \cos B$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ and $B$ be two real symmetric matrices such that $A^{2018} = B^{2018}$. Show that $\cos A = \cos B$.

(And is it true that $\sin A = \sin B$ ?)

We can write $A = PDP^T$ and $B = QD'Q^T$ by the spectral theorem ;

Hence $PD^{2018}P^T = QD'^{2018}Q^T$

Do you have a hint to solve this?

Comment: What is $S_n(\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: I am curious about where this problem comes from.  In particular, I wonder if it comes from a competition (math contests often use the year in their problems).

Comment: @anon the asker has already referenced this fact (i.e. the spectral theorem) in the body of his question

Comment: $B=-A$ gives a lot of counterexamples for sine.

Comment: Yes, I put this, under parenthesis, because it was the end of the exercise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$A^2$ and $B^2$ are positive definite matrices satisfying
$$
(A^2)^{1009} = (B^2)^{1009}
$$
It follows that $A^2 = B^2$.

Now, note that the power series for $\cos(A)$ may be written as a power series on $A^2$.

It is easy to come up with a counterexample for $\sin$.  If you like, take $A = \pi/2$, $B = -\pi/2$ (both $1 \times 1$ matrices).

Answer (score 2):

First note that $A^{2018}$ and $B^{2018}$ are positive.

The function ``$2018$-th root ($\sqrt[2018]{\ast}$)'' is defined for all positive matrices, and it takes "a positive matrix $X$ to the only positive matrix $B$ in the algebra generated by $A$ such that $B^{2018}=X$"

Moreover, if $X$ is symmetric then $\sqrt[2018]{X^{2018}}=|X|$, where $|X|=\sqrt{X^2}$.

From this, we get $|A|=|B|$. Take cosine on both sides to get $\cos|A|=\cos|B|$, and again use symmetry to conclude that
$$\cos A=\cos|A|=\cos|B|=\cos B$$

All of this works in any C*-algebra and $A,B$ self-adjoint elements and if $\cos$ is replaced by any even continuous function (note that in this case the trick with the Taylor expansion of $\cos$ mentioned by others doesn't work anymore).

Comment: Or note that $f(t)=t^{1/1009}$ is continuous on $\Bbb R$ since $1009$ is odd; hence $A^2=f(A^{2018})=f(B^{2018})=B^2$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Works as well. I think this argument is the same as the second and third paragraph, but in opposite order, because then we need to take square roots and get $|A|=|B|$.

Comment: Of course it's essentially the same. But no, we don't need to take square roots! The reason I mentioned this is that once we know $A^2=B^2$ we done, since $\cos(t)$ depends only on $t^2$; no need to worry about $|A|$ and $|B|$ at all.